# set the width of a kendo numeric text box with tag helpers

Tags: telerik, tag-helpers

The title pretty much says it, I have searched the documentation and all I can find is this:

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/tag-helpers/editors/numerictextbox/overview

Which does not address it at all.

Here is my current line of code:

```
    <kendo-numerictextbox name="currency" id="txtCheckNumber"  format="#" min="0" enable="true" max="9999999999" spinners="false" value="10001" > </kendo-numerictextbox>
```

I have tried the obvious width="100px" and width="100" with no success

Comment: I can't find anything either.  For the kendo-dropdownlist, you can use style (style="width: 200px;") but that doesn't seem to be supported with the numerictextbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could figure out how to set the width was to override the Kendo styles on the wrapper spans and the input.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .k-widget.k-numerictextbox {
        width: 100px !important;
    }
    .k-numeric-wrap.k-state-default {
        width: 100px !important;
    }
    .k-numeric-wrap input {
        width: 100px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: that would do it!